# A call to web service which returns an image, audio and all heavy weight data types

Tags: database, web-services, image, security, audio

Hello all I need your advice on this please.

Implementing an image database as a service **vs** giving access to the database directly in a client-server architecture.

Which one is the best taking security, performance and other factors into consideration.

Images and audio clips are better to be stored in a file system rather than a database. How do I make a call.
client---->web service---->database---->file system(which has images and audio)
Is above description a good way to make a call, or can any one suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give clients direct access to your database.  Provide a web service.  This gives you increased flexibility to change your DB schema later, and improved control over your security.

I would store all of your resource information (file name, mime type, meta data, etc.) in the database and then build a web service that returns files when requested.  This is a common way of doing things.

In addition, there is no need for the clients to know the file names or structures on your server.  The clients can make a request to your web service, and the web service can return the file data directly.

Comment: It goes like this,client--->Hub--->web service---->database--->file system.Sorry for that, client doesnot have access to the web service here.

Comment: Is there a limit on the payload of the data being transferred between the web service and the application using the service?